# Conflicting setter for property in jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have a problem in my webservice controller, due to jackson's serialisation of a third party object.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for
>   property "X": ThirdPartyClass#setX(1 params) vs ThirdPartyClass#setX(1
>   params)

I've read that you can solve it thanks to MixIn annotation.

In my controller i'm giving a list, i'd like to know if there is a way to automatically define somewhere the use of the MixInAnnotation ?

If i had to do return a String instead of objects, i'd do something like that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(xxx);
return mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

Nevertheless, my controller is giving List:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> getMyObjects
```

and several times returning MyObject in other methods, and so i'd like to declare only one time the use of the MixInAnnotation for jackson serialisation ?

Thank you,
RoD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the "Spring Way" of doing this by following the steps provided in the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

> If you want to replace the default `ObjectMapper` completely, define a `@Bean` of that type and mark it as `@Primary`.
>
> Defining a `@Bean` of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` will allow you to customize both default `ObjectMapper` and `XmlMapper` (used in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` respectively).
>
> Another way to customize Jackson is to add beans of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module` to your context. They will be registered with every bean of type `ObjectMapper`, providing a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application.

Basically this means that if you simply register a `Module` as a bean with the provided mixin-settings you should be all set and there will be no need to define your own `ObjectMapper` or to alter the `HttpMessageConverter`s.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to do this, i customised the Jackson JSON mapper in Spring Web MVC.

Custom mapper:

```
@Component
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        this.addMixInAnnotations(Target.class, SourceMixIn.class);
    }
}
```

Register the new mapper at start up of spring context:

```
@Component
public class JacksonInit {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private CustomObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getMessageConverters();
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter : messageConverters) {
            if (messageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter m = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) messageConverter;
                m.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to that, i didn't modify my WebService Controller.